# Convert infix to postfix in YACC(Bison)

Tags: expression, bison, yacc, infix-notation

I have been trying to convert an infix expression to postfix expression using YACC(Bison) with no success. I would like to know how it can be done? Sample code will be awesome :)

Comment: Perhaps you could post your attempts and explain how/where it failed instead of simply asking for "the codez"?

Comment: I have no clue how to do it and google wasn't of much help either!

Comment: No clue how to convert in- to postfix? No clue how to use yacc/bison? Something else? I can't imagine the first two question can't be easily answered through a web-search. Your question "as is" is just a plea for someone else to do your (home)work, and therefor, not likely to be answered is my experience. A bit of context would also help here: *why* do you want to use a parser generator here? It's overkill.

Comment: maybe [this](http://sites.google.com/site/techcrunchorg/l-p-lab/infix-to-postfix-yacc-) can help

Answer (score 9):

This is my solution:

#### gram.l file:

```
%{
#include"y.tab.h"
extern int yylval;
%}
%%
[0-9]+  {yylval=atoi(yytext); return NUM;}
\n      return 0;
.       return *yytext;
%%

int yywrap(){
    return 1;
}
```

#### gram.y file:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}
%token NUM
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%right NEGATIVE
%%
S:  E {printf("\n");}
    ;
E:  E '+' E {printf("+");}
    |   E '*' E {printf("*");}
    |   E '-' E {printf("-");}
    |   E '/' E {printf("/");}
    |   '(' E ')'
    |   '-' E %prec NEGATIVE {printf("-");}
    |   NUM     {printf("%d", yylval);}
    ;
%%

int main(){
    yyparse();
}

int yyerror (char *msg) {
    return printf ("error YACC: %s\n", msg);
}
```

#### shell:

```
yacc -d gram.y
flex gram.l
cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c
./a.out
```

#### example input and output:

```
2+6*2-5/3
262*+53/-
```